# Is there a term for adjectives / modifiers that don't, at face value, seem to apply to the noun modified?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, literary-techniques, literary-device

There's a verse in Bob Seger's song **Mainstreet** that has this wonderful little seemingly-nonsensical word pairing:

> There was this long, lovely dancer in a little club downtown; 
>   I loved to watch her do her stuff. 
>   Through the long, lonely nights she filled my sleep, 
>   her body softly swaying to that **smoky beat**.

On face-value, the word "smoky" to describe a "beat" just doesn't make sense; smoky isn't really a quality that a [musical] beat can have. And yet, the the words *do* make sense together and evoke a clearer (err, smokier) image of the nightclub.

Is there a term for this literary device? Are there other examples that come to mind?

Comment: I suspect you're over-thinking this.  "Smoky beat" just refers to music that has a sort of sultry, sensuous nature to it.

Comment: Agree with @HotLicks - I don't see "smoky" as describing the night-club here. Beats also can't technically be fat, dirty, hot, etc.

Comment: Maybe. In any case, it led to the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @mattsoave Since it led to the answer you were looking for, I conclude that you previously had heard of that concept, but forgot the name of it. Now you are satisfied. But, in your question, you gave a bad example—this is *most* unfortunate for future readers! Perhaps because your error slipped through, your question already has been misapplied as [another question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504500/why-are-they-nude-photos/504859)'s duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a form of metonymy using adjectives as what are called **transferred epithets**.

Nordquist, in [Grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/transferredepitheterm.htm) gives a good overview, including the definition

> A figure of speech in which an epithet (or adjective) grammatically
>   qualifies a noun other than the person or thing it is actually
>   describing. Also known in rhetoric as hypallage.

There needs to be *some* connection between the adjective and the rest of the statement.

He adds

> A transferred epithet often involves shifting a modifier from the
>   animate to the inanimate, as in the phrases "cheerful money,"
>   "sleepless night," and "suicidal sky."

'A quiet pint' (the surroundings are quiet) and 'a proud day' (some of the principals at the ceremony etc are fittingly proud) are other commonly used examples.

Gandalf's critical analysis of Bilbo's 'Good morning!'/s [[*Goodreads*](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/14559-good-morning-said-bilbo-and-he-meant-it-the-sun)] (or Bilbo's acquiescence) is partly based on transference.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage) sees the sense in including similar noun phrases employing attributive nouns rather than adjectives as premodifiers in the class:

> Hypallage ... is a figure of speech in which the syntactic
>   relationship between two terms is interchanged, or—more frequently—a modifier is syntactically linked to an item other than the one that
>   it modifies semantically

(but note that 'hypallage' is not restricted to the 'transferred epithet' sense);

*salad days* and *landscape photography* are examples.

.................

A complication is that dictionary compilers rightly pick up on the non-central usages as they become idiomatic, and (rightly or wrongly) add secondary denotations (as opposed to say listing such usages under 'idioms'. For example, a possibility is

'proud' as in 'proud day': 'used to describe a time, event etc when there was/is ... reasonable grounds for pride in someone's or some group's accomplishments / when there was/is ... such pride'. It can then be argued that the defined subsense is no longer a transferred sense.

Comment: Nice question; nice answer.  As a postscript may I add Synaesthesia? This is when a listener actually sees trumpet music as scarlet, feels 'three' is colder than 'eight', or smells a bass sequence as smoky.