# Why are they 'nude photos'?

Tags: idioms, word-usage, attributive-nouns, compound-words

Recent news events in the US have resulted in many headlines about "nude photos of young women" and variations.

Obviously it's the women who are nude, not the photos, so why does this phrasing persist? Is it an idiom, or does it just flow better, or is it some other nuance of usage that I haven't seen in other situations?

Edit: I don't think the linked question is directly on point (though I do see the connection), nor do I think just saying "nude photos are photos of nudes, duh" is an informative answer or comment. Defining nude photos as *photos of nudes* ignores the fact that the headline refers to *photos of women*.

Comment: It’s no different than pictures of me playing baseball being called my baseball photos or calling the pictures of me swimming my swimming photos.

Comment: A nude photo is nude in the same sense that a beer bottle is beer.

Comment: For the same reason as there are cat videos

Comment: See also: vacation photos, yearbook photos

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦ A beer bottle is a beer bottle regardless of whether it contains beer or not.

Comment: None of these examples (except maybe "cat videos") have the peculiar Munchausen-syndrome-by-proxy nature of OP's phrase. On the other hand, there is something going on here beyond mere idiom. So far, @TaliesinMerlin seems to be closest.

Comment: @Spencer precisely my point. I choose my words very carefully.

Comment: @Spencer A beer bottle is a beer bottle when it contains beer, else it is only a bottle that looks like a beer bottle or a bottle with a label that says it is used for beer. No?

Comment: @Jalene No, it's a "beer bottle".

Comment: But they are not “nude young photos of women” or “young nude photos of women”

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, this is a case of a transferred epithet, but the question is still not quite a duplicate. What makes this case specially puzzling is that the noun **from** which the epithet is transferred, *women*, **remains** a part of the phrase; that is not the case in the examples discussed in the other question and the answer to it. One can understand why the epithet would be transferred when the noun to which it was originally attached is dropped, but it is puzzling why it would be transferred when the noun remains.

Comment: @Jim - Would you ever refer to *baseball photos of women*? If not then your example misses the point.

Comment: cf. _nude photos of old men_

Comment: @jsw29 I can't agree. There are over 125 000 Google hits for "nude photos of young men". If the question is about a perceived gender bias in the use of the word 'nude', it needs resubmitting. This is a duplicate.

Comment: @JimMack, preface or idioms itself describing the nature of photo.. it gives more focus/attention then photo of the nudes. When you say 'nude' brain is geeting immediate attention without following rest of the words..

Comment: In German, a nude photo in the usual sense is "ein Nacktfoto" while a photo which is nude would be "ein nacktes Foto". English does not mark the grammatical roles of words strongly compared to related languages which have kept more inflections.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Could you provide several examples of this type of photo?

Comment: @Spencer I disagree. If the bottle is unlabeled, it is simply a bottle. It might be the shape one commonly associates as containing beer, but being unlabeled, it could be for water, or soda, or anything else able to be poured. It is only the labelling (or contents) that make it a 'beer bottle'.

Comment: @JimMack, why would one not refer to *baseball photos of women*?  Sounds like an entirely reasonable construction to me: if you take photos at a baseball game, and specifically choose to photograph female players, you've taken baseball photos of women.

Comment: @RegDwigнt If your point was that a beer bottle is a beer bottle even if it contains no beer, you're saying that a nude photo is a nude photo even if it contains no nudity?  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The  point RegDwight makes about the beer bottle is not cryptic. A beer bottle is not (made of) "beer" just as a nude photo is not "nude=naked".

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the [claimed question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247157/is-there-a-term-for-adjectives-modifiers-that-dont-at-face-value-seem-to-ap), simply because the word "nude" here is not a transferred epithet. With its definition as "depicting...naked people," it applies to the word, "photo" directly without transference. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/504503/17186). That the adjective "nude" doesn't, at face value, seem to apply to the noun "photo" simply comes from ignorance of that definition.

Answer (score 50):

Collocations modifying *photo* often don't refer to the photo as a physical object. They instead refer to the subject of the photo, or what's depicted in the image.

To demonstrate this, here are the most common collocations for ____ photo according to the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). I have bolded the ones that describe the image (source, subject, or whatever) and italicized the ones that describe a property of the physical photograph. Other results are left unchanged. Numbers describe frequency within the corpus.

- these (434)
- **family** (379)
- *two* (316)
- take (243)
- *color* (234)
- **AP** (225)
- those (222)
- taking (180)
- *digital* (168)
- *old* (160)
- **scene** (147)
- *three* (135)
- **nude** (129)
- *framed* (124)
- **satellite** (122)
- *black-and-white* (113)
- took (112)
- **aerial** (91)
- *four* (87)
- *five* (84)
- snapping (82)
- **wedding** (63)

Out of these results, a **family** photo is understood to be a photo of a family, just as a **wedding** photo is understood to be a photo of a wedding. Similarly, English has other constructions, like **nude** photo. The same positioning can also describe provenance (AP photo, satellite photo, aerial photo), quality of photo (black-and-white photo, color photo), physical status (framed photo, digital photo), and so on.

Hearers understand **nude photo** to refer to what's in the photo because of established usage. Also, the idea of a photo in the "nude" does not make much sense, so the physical interpretation of the object is unlikely. Many media objects have this quality; a ___ book can refer to either the physical object (big book, hardcover book) or to a quality of the text inside (a sad book, a scholarly book). A bit of logic and some arbitrary usage rules determine how people interpret collocations involving media objects.

Comment: One can easily see how *a photo of a family* becomes *a family photo*. One can also see why that happens: the latter formulation is simpler and easier to integrate into longer sentences. That, however, is not analogous to the present case. If *photos of nude women* followed the same pattern, it would turn into *nude-women photos*, but that's not what actually happens. The puzzling question is why does the adjective *nude* move to *photos*, while the *of women* construction remains. *Photos of tall women* would never become *tall photos of women*.

Comment: I don't see the equivalent formation necessarily being *photo(s) of nude women*. It could easily be *photo of a nude*. Compare to Dali's *[Study of a Nude](https://www.salvador-dali.org/en/artwork/catalogue-raisonne-paintings/obra/156/study-of-a-nude)*. *Nude* would thus be an attributive noun in *nude photo*, just like *family* in *family photo* or *wedding* in *wedding photo*.

Comment: @jsw29 *Nude* is a noun - meaning "naked model/person" (this usage has been common for around two centuries, so it's not exactly new). So it's exactly analogous to "family photo". The only confusing part is that *nude* is also used as an adjective (as the latin original *nudus* it came from).

Comment: @Luaan On that analysis I don't see how we would be able to say *nude photos of his ex*, so I think jsw29 is right.

Comment: @Minty "Nude photo" is a photo of a nude. "Nude photo of his ex" is a photo of a nude, who happens to be his ex (or was made by his ex, clunky as it is). Does "Leg photo of his ex" sound weird to you? For bonus points, *nude* (noun) also already means "a depiction of a nude person". If you follow the progression from "a depiction of a nude person" to *another* (very natural) adjectivisation, you get "nudity-depicting photo", so in this interpretation *nude* in "nude photos" would be an adjective, but wouldn't really mean *bare*. These kinds of changes happen very fast in human communication.

Comment: @Minty In the end, the most important part is - it's not confusing anyone. Nobody mistakenly believes that the photos are bare of their covering, for example (unless it's clear from context). These kinds of shortenings are extremely common. "Cycling photos of his ex" also isn't anything weird, is it? It clearly means "Cycling-depicting photos", and nobody would think the *photos* cycle. You're right that the "X" in "X photos" behaves more usually as an adjective, but "X" itself can be pretty much anything.

Comment: @Luaan in the context of a question asking how is it that *nude photos* means what it does, I don't agree that that's the most important part - in fact I don't think it's important at all. I'm not clear whether you are arguing that in *nude photo of his ex*, *nude* is still a noun. I can't see how it can be - I haven't closed my mind on that, but saying what it means doesn't help. The point is that if it is not a noun in that sentence, it is harder to argue that it is a noun in *nude photos*.

Comment: @Minty So, what is *cycling* in *Cycling photos of his ex*? Mind you, I'm not necessarily saying that *nude* in *nude photo* must be a noun. But if you do treat it as an adjective, it's a *different* adjective, with a different (though related) meaning - some sort of contraction of *nude depicting* or such. My main point is that regardless of the interpretation, *nude photos* is not some weird exception - it's a very common thing that happens in language.

Comment: @Luaan I don't really disagree with that, but can't square it with your original comment, where you were responding to jsw29's comment that *nude* is an adjective by saying that it's a noun.

Comment: If *nude photos of his ex* means *photos of a nude, namely his ex* and *cycling photos of his ex* follows the same pattern, that means *cycling photos of his ex* means *photos of a cycling, namely his ex*, which can't be right. I think the first one means *photos of his ex, nude* - but I'm not sure the second one means *photos of his ex, cycling*...

Comment: ... I would definitely include photos taken in the pub after a day's cycling as cycling photos, even though they don't show anybody cycling. I think the phrase means something more like *photos of his ex related to cycling*, whereas the *nude* version can't mean *photos of his ex related to nude*, so I think this is a false parallel.

Comment: Just to drop a bit of input in this discussion (I've been reading and thinking, so thank you both) I'm noncommital about whether *nude* in *nude photos* is an attributive noun or an adjective. At least for *nude*, I see both possibilities. Defining potential rephrasings (like "photo of a nude" or "photo of someone nude" or "photo of someone who is nude") helps tease out how particular collocations may be understood. My original comment was intended to caution against overdetermining how *nude* has to function.

Comment: The important information I will remember from this answer is that the ratio of nude photos per wedding photos is about 2:1.

Comment: +1 for the *sad book* comparison. I will be sure to try and cheer up all my sad books when I get home.

Comment: @jsw29: "Tall photos" could refer to the physical size or aspect ratio of the photo, so there's ambiguity there.

Answer (score 26):

> **nude**  ADJECTIVE
>   ...
>   1.1 [attributive] Depicting or performed by naked people.
>   *‘she won't do any nude scenes’*
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nude)

Comment: This is just a dictionary definition without any explanation whatsoever. Might just as well post a link in a comment. BTW it's no longer Oxford Dictionaries, it's now called Lexico.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That makes this answer one of those notorious ***nomina nuda*** which people are always railing about. Hard to blame them, really.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ... you are right.  Lexico.

Comment: While it's just a definition it does address the question.

Comment: While in the form of a quote, this answer identifies which definition is relevant and even provides an example.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question at all. Simply stating that the word *nude* is an adjective doesn't say anything about how adjectives work in English, and providing an example is useless when the op himself already did so.

Comment: OP wasn't asking for the definition of "nude", he was asking why photos of nude people were being referred to as "nude photos", when such a phrase could also be interpreted as the photos being nude rather than the subject of the photos being nude.

Comment: How does it not address the question? It states clearly that the word "nude" can mean depicting or performed by naked people. Ie; the "nude photo" is a photo depicting nude photos. To say this answer is invalid would seem to also argue the question wasn't valid either, since the answer was as easy as looking up the word nude.

Comment: @alex.pilon if you read the question, it's not about the definition of nude, it's about the placement that applies it to photo.  This answer is completely ignoring the actual question to focus on an irrelevant detail.

Comment: I agree with @alex.pilon. The definition _does_ read. "Depicting ... naked people".  How could that apply to anything other than the photo?

Comment: The OP already knows that the word **can** be so used; he is seeking an **explanation** of that use.

Comment: @jsw29 The question was: 'I thought *nude* can only apply to people'. The answer is: 'Well, there's another meaning of *nude* that does not'. I can't really see what else needs explaining

Comment: @jsw29 And does the dictionary definition merely LMGTFY'd here go beyond licensing this particular (nude pictures = pictures of nudes) usage? Does it address the fact that some see 'nude pictures' as implying 'pictures of female nudes'?

Comment: @RonLugge The definition clarifies the use of the placement. The placement indicates that (sorry not sure the correct term) "subject", ie; the photo, is depicting naked people. I'm unsure what irrelevant detail is being focused on.

Answer (score 24):

It’s a way to refer to photos with nude subjects. As you can see from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nude%20photo%2Cnude%20photos&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cnude%20photo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnude%20photo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNude%20Photo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnude%20photos%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnude%20photos%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNude%20photos%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNude%20Photos%3B%2Cc0) this expression took off from the ‘60s/70s when pictures portraying nude people, generally women, started to become popular; the same expression was used  earlier  referring to  [paintings](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nude%20photos%2C%20nude%20paintings&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cnude%20photos%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnude%20photos%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNude%20photos%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNude%20Photos%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnude%20paintings%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnude%20paintings%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNude%20paintings%3B%2Cc0)

***[Nude:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nude)***

> (of a photograph, painting, statue, etc.) being or prominently displaying a representation of the nude human figure.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: Thanks for the Ngram. It reinforces the idea that the phrase has become an idiom.

Comment: @JimMack Enough of all this beating around the bush already. It's time to let the cat out of the bag and spill the beans: in **exactly what fashion** could *"nude photos"* ***EVER*** be considered any sort of "idiom"?? You're clearly barking up the wrong tree here. The elephant in the room is that timeless refrain, "A noun simply qualified doth never an idiom make." Since it takes two to tango, the ball's in your court now, Roger Federer.

Comment: @tchrist -would  “black photo” mean a photo of black people? There is something idiomatic in “nude photo”, though it is not an idiom.

Comment: There is utterly no connection to "idiom" here, @JimMack .  it's exactly the same as saying an "action movie" or a "family holiday" or a "color photo" or a "pop song".  It's an "adjective".

Comment: @tchrist - the 'idiomatic' part, it seems to me, comes from the notion that *nude photos* means *photos of nudes*. But the headline phrase is already *photos of women*. So the *nude* seems to have migrated from modifying *women* to modifying *photos*. I don't mean to say that *nude photos* is itself an idiom, only that this usage seems idiomatic.

Answer (score 10):

It happens fairly often in English that an adjective is "transferred" from one subject to another, even when it doesn't strictly speaking apply to the latter, provided it is still *relevant* (in some sense) to the latter. This often begins as a mild figure of speech — see https://www.thoughtco.com/transferred-epithet-1692558 for various examples — but in a great many cases this develops into an independent sense. This happens particularly often when one subject denotes a person and one subject denotes a thing, perhaps because this rarely creates any confusion. Examples include *vegetarian* (vegetarian people eat vegetarian food), *healthy* (exercise is healthy because it's likely to make people healthier), *happy* (a happy ending is one intended to make the audience happy), and *unfortunate* (you are unfortunate if an unfortunate event befalls you).

Answer (score 7):

**Nude photos** is a [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) that has become [idiomatic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiomatic) and manifests in slang such as "**[nudies](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nudies)**" or simply "**nudes**". The phrase "nude photos of X" does indeed seem like a retro-construction. This phrasing is also more euphemistic or neutral, perhaps, since as you mentioned, technically, it would be "X" who is nude, but "X" is not the grammatical subject (it is instead within the prepositional "of X").

@user240918 and @GEdgar also make good points.

Note Webster:

> **nude** (adj) *bare, naked, nude, bald, barren* mean deprived of naturally or conventionally appropriate covering. ... *nude* applies especially to the unclothed human figure.

Comment: I think the answer is that it's now idiomatic, as you point out. Many of the other answers and comments seem to just state the obvious.

Comment: @JimMack This is wrong. It is not in any way idiomatic. It means what it literally says. Therefore it is not idiomatic. A cat photo is a photo of a cat. A clock hand is the hand of a clock; it is not a hand that is clocky. Cock crow is not a crow that is cocky.  Child photos aren't photos that will someday grow up. Rather, they are photos ***OF*** children.

Comment: It is not idiomatic in the "a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words (e.g., rain cats and dogs, see the light)", but it is idiomatic in the second sense "a form of expression natural to a language, person, or group of people." Both are from OED

Comment: @tchrist I asked the question 'Is a dead metaphor still a metaphor?' way back. It could well be argued that the **primary** sense of _nude_ being _naked_, 'nude photographs', using 'nude' in other than its archetypal sense but in a universally accepted way, is an example of an idiom.

Answer (score 6):

It's often the case when describing *containers* that we use adjectives that describe their contents rather than their own intrinsic properties. (containers isn't a technical term but it fit the concept).

For example

- a physics textbook *isn't physics*, rather the contents describe knowledge we have on the field of physics
- your family photos *aren't related to you*, rather they're photos in which the subject is your family.
- a beer bottle *isn't made of beer*, rather it contains beer.

I would not consider the phrase "nude photo" idiomatic, it's just the standard way of saying that the photo's subject is nude.

Comment: None of your examples involve adjectives; I think you're looking for the word "modifier".

Answer (score 3):

From the OED, bold emphasis mine:

> **nude**
>
> A3c. (*adj*) Of a work of art, form of entertainment, etc.: involving or **portraying one or more naked or scantily clad people**; performed without clothing. Also of an actor or model: that performs or poses unclothed.
>
> - 1869   D. N. Camp Amer. Year-bk. I. 791   Her charms, so freely exhibited on the stage at this time that to her example the successful origin of the nude drama is attributed, were also used as the means of unnumbered conquests.
> - 1874   Atlantic Monthly Nov. 532   We, of the legitimate, who regard the nude drama as a highly demoralizing innovation..went our several ways.
> - 1888   Dict. National Biogr. at Daniel, George   Several extant oil-paintings..are not improbably the work of George himself, as is also the full-length nude study of a nymph.
> - 1959   Listener 15 Jan. 132/3   The night-clubs in Calvin's city put on nude shows.
> - 1974   Publishers Weekly 26 Aug. 250/3   A novel about a nude model who longs for true love.
> - 1982   A. Maupin Further Tales of City 81   Some of the boys did an impressive nude water ballet to the music of ‘Tea for Two’.
> - 2000   Country Music People May 30/3   He shouldn't have taken those nude photos, but no matter.
>
> B2a. (*n*) Art. With *the*: the naked or undraped human figure conceived of as an aesthetic object; **the representation of this in art**.
>
> after French †nud painting of a naked human figure (1676). Compare Anglo-Norman and Middle French nu, nud (early 12th cent.; French nu), Italian nudo (a1294; a1472 in sense ‘**painting of a naked human figure**’)
>
> - 1760   D. Webb Inq. Beauties Painting iv. 51   The result of this habit is evident, when our first artists come to design the nud.
> - 1782   R. Cumberland Anecd. Painters Spain I. 56   Being most in the nude, their crime will in some people's judgment appear their recommendation.
> - 1854   T. Martin Correggio iii. 65   I love the nude; Garments are nothing but the veils to beauty.
> - 1868   R. Browning Ring & Bk. I. i. 4   Modern chalk drawings, studies from the nude.
> - 1887   F. M. Crawford Saracinesca i   The French school had not [yet] demonstrated the startling distinction between the nude and the naked.
> - 1915   W. Cather Song of Lark i. xvi. 111   Ray found that his brakemen were likely to have what he termed ‘a taste for the nude in art’.
> - 1974   M. Ayrton Midas Consequence viii. 208   Most of what I do is founded on, or derived from, the nude, the stripped human body, as is most of the good bronze sculpture in this world.
> - 1992   Crafts Mar. 19/2   The nude is confronted in life class (and notice it is not called drawing class).

Comment: Is the  fact that the OED gives a full entry to this usage of “nude” an indication of idiomatic expression?

Comment: @user240918 no, it gives a full entry to every single distinct usage and meaning. There are 15 for "nude". There are no listings for "nude" in the Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms.

Comment: Do they give the same entry and usage examples for “family photo” or “holiday photo” for instance?

Comment: I am not saying it is an idiom, but that it is an idiomatic usage.

Comment: @user240918 for "family" there are additionally 50 compounds given, of which "family album" is the closest - `(a) a book in which contributions, such as verses and signatures, are inscribed by and for members of a particular family (cf. album n.2 1a) (now rare);  (b) a family's photograph album (cf. album n.2 1c).` These are noted as being special cases of `Of, relating to, or belonging to a (particular) family or household`.

Comment: @user240918 it is neither idion, nor idiomatic usage, whatever you think the difference is between them.

Comment: The difference between the two is clearly stated by the OED.

Comment: @user240918 `a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from the meanings of the individual words` vs `Relating to or exhibiting the forms of expression, grammatical constructions, phrases, etc. used in a distinctive way in a particular language, dialect, or language variety, formerly especially those considered nonstandard or colloquial. Now usually spec.: established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from the meanings of the individual words.`

Comment: It is not idiomatic in the "a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words (e.g., rain cats and dogs, see the light)", ***but it is idiomatic in the second sense "a form of expression natural to a language, person, or group of people." Both are from OED*** – Carly 14 hours ago

Comment: @user240918 If you are using that definition then _everything_ in standard English is idiomatic. Everyone here will assume the usual definition instead.

Answer (score 0):

Testing this out against my native speaker's understanding, I think there is a general pattern here. It may be relatively new, but I can't remember any time when I would not have understood it or might have been told off by an older person for abusing the language.

The pattern is that " photo", often means "photo depicting a " (or s plural). Tree photos. Hummingbird photos. Lorry photos. Cloud photos. Chair photos. None confuse me or sound wrong. Old computer photos (which parses as photos of old computers more than old photos of computers in my mind).

It's not unambiguous. "Newspaper photos" are likely to be snippets out of newspapers, not photos of newspapers. "Estate agent photos" are likely to be of houses for sale, not the people selling them.

BTW Is this a particular issue for people whose first language is a Latin one? I ask because this reminded me of a bleakly comic scene in *"A Canticle for Liebowicz"* wherein a few hundred years after a nuclear war destroyed the world, a monk whose first language is Latin who believes that "fallouts" were demons the destroyed his ancient world, is trying to make sense of  a sign stating "Fallout survival shelter capacity 12".

Edit: I think [Alexandre Aubrey's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/504652/191909) answer nails it. It's all to do with the directly modified object being a container.

Comment: In spanish, the appropriate use of prepositions will change the meaning:
A "nude photo", literally translated "foto desnuda", has not the same meaning (it would be roughly "a naked photo", made with no tricks). Instead we say "foto de desnudo(s)". Note that we changed the gender of nude to "neutral" as is not referring itself to the photograpy -in Spanish a feminine noun- and we added the preposition "de", that in this case is telling us the theme of the photo (lit: "photo of nude").

Comment: As a side note, I think the wordplay of the novel comes less with differences between the latin languages grammar and more with not knowing what Fallout is: without that knowledge, a Fallout survival shelter can mean either "a shelter where you survive the (radioactive) fallout)" or "a shelter where you survive the fallout (race))". It helps that a Fallout can be interpreted as "some(thing/one) that fell out (from the sky)", aka a Fallen Angel. Given the religious background of some of the characters (I only looked at the synopsis, so may be wrong), this can be a possible interpretation.

Comment: @Stormbolter his concern is that the shelter may contain fallouts, and whether they could have survived for  centuries, and why would any person have wanted to help them to do so, and he is grappling with the adjectival use of nouns that this question was about ... but I'd never spotted the possible connection between "fallout" and fallen angel that might explain how the misinterpretation could arise. I'll have to read it again now. It's a great book.

Answer (score 0):

> Recent news events in the US have resulted in many headlines about "nude photos of young women" and variations.
>
> [W]hy does this phrasing persist?

Quoting (adding emphasis) from Joseph Henrich's 2016 book, [The Secret of Our Success: How Culture Is Driving Human Evolution, Domesticating Our Species, and Making Us Smarter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691178437): from p. 231:

> [L]anguages arise from long-term cumulative cultural evolution. Like
> other aspects of culture ... our ... spoken languages ... have evolved
> via cultural transmission over generations to improve the efficiency
> and quality of communication, and to **adapt to the details of local
> communication contexts,** including ... social norms (like taboos).

From p. 232:

> [A]mong our ancestors, cultural evolution accumulated, integrated, and
> honed many useful **communicative elements** over long stretches of time
> into increasingly complex repertoires[.]

Presumably this phrasing persists (within our local communication context) because, in our attempts to communicate this general idea, each of the exact communicative elements "nude photos" and "young women" contains enough pressure (perhaps arising from social norms) to survive (rather than dropping to the cutting room floor): perhaps this is because both elements are salacious, or refer to some current political themes, or otherwise have impact, which is presumably desired by the news headline editors. By this phrasing, the editors communicate to us a doublet of ideas: that the women are young, and that, normally, they are not nude. Presumably they are nice, acceptable people. This meaning is less conveyed by the phrasing, "photos of nude, young women."

So, the fact that both communicative elements persist (or that this phrasing persists) follows no grammatical rule: i.e., it is idiosyncratic (rather than idiomatic, precisely speaking).

Also, the very fact that our language productions typically follow various grammatical patterns is itself merely the result of our idiosyncratically weighing those grammatical patterns along with many other cultural factors, in our attempt to achieve success.

Comment: Are you saying that this wording is needed to convey the idea that the women are normally not nude? Does anybody really think that 'photos of nude, young women' implies otherwise?

Comment: @jsw29 Arguably, "nude photos of young women" labels and objectifies them the least, "photos of young, nude women" does so the most, and "photos of nude, young women" falls in the middle—wouldn't you say?