# What is it called when a word is used as an adjective to provide color to a description or activity?

Tags: adjectives

For instance:
"That was an **insane** amount of money"
The word "insane" is used to indicate that the person describing the money thought it was a very large amount.

"That was a **pro** move catching the glass before it hit the ground" 
Here "pro" is used to acknowledge a combination of skill/speed/luck but in reality no one is professionally catching glasses before they hit the ground.

What is the term for using words incorrectly to add additional "spice" to a sentence?

Comment: There is nothing wrong about these uses. Words change meaning over time. You judge these word choices because they are so colloquial, but they are not any more incorrect than "That is a wild story!" or "She was an exceptional student."

Comment: There's no precise term for such usage. You might possibly refer to the metaphorical use of the words, but then English is full of metaphors. The *jocular* use of the words, possibly???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a term for adjectives / modifiers that don't, at face value, seem to apply to the noun modified?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247157/is-there-a-term-for-adjectives-modifiers-that-dont-at-face-value-seem-to-ap) These are known as _transferred epithets_. 'A quiet pint'. 'A proud day'. 'An insane amount of money spent on the Exposition' (ie the people allocating that amount of money were insane [allegedly]). 'A pro move' (one a pro might well make). Dictionary definitions often broaden to encompass these transferred usages.